# Are there any module for fixed-point converting and operation in python?

Tags: python, fixed-point

I wondering are there any module for floating point convert to fixed-point number. The fixed-point mentioned here is in base 2, so some example is like:

> fixed point expression = 2^1 + 2^0 + a*2^-1 + b*2^-2.....

what I am finding is some module can do like this:

> input is 0.68751( floating point ), and specify some accuracy(like 3)
>
> and output is 0.6875 cause 0.5 + 0.125 + 0.0625

I have seen module `Decimal`, it has `quantize` method did almost what I want, but it is decimal instead in binary base.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I misunderstand, but I think in your `0.6875 cause 0.5 + 0.125 + 0.0625` example the `accuracy` should be **4** since `0.0625=2**-4`

Anyway, you can use fixed-point libraray like [numfi](https://numfi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create fixed point number based on floating number

```
>>> from numfi import numfi    
>>> x = numfi(0.68751,1,6,4) 
>>> x
numfi([0.6875]) s6/4-r/s
```

you can also use this simple function if you don't need fixed point arithmetic

```py
np.round(num*(2**f)) * 2**-f # f is fraction length
```

`np.round` can be replaced by `np.floor`/`np.ceil`/`astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a python module for that, **fxpmath**. You can find more information at:

https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath

Here an example:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

x = Fxp(0.68751, True, 8, 3)   # (val, signed, n_word, n_frac)

print(x)
print('precision = {}\n'.format(x.precision))

y = Fxp(0.68751, True, 8, 4)   # (val, signed, n_word, n_frac)

print(y)
print('precision = {}\n'.format(y.precision))

print(x+y)
```

Results:

```
0.625
precision = 0.125

0.6875
precision = 0.0625

1.3125
```